# `mongoMappingContext` error when upgrading Spring Boot from 1.5.3 to 2.3.4

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, pom.xml

While upgrading my project from Spring Boot 1 to 2 (specifically, 2.3.4), I encountered the following issue:

```
Error creating bean with name 'mongoMappingContext' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataConfiguration.class]
```

In my pom file, the versions are aligned, like so:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <!-- implicitly its version is 2.3.4.RELEASE -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
            <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
            <!-- implicitly its version is 4.3.1 -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>3.12.8</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
```

In my application.yml I have set

```
spring:
    main:
        allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

I have done a lengthy research and haven't found a solution to this issue.

NOTES:

1. In this particular project, I need my mongo databse to achieve multitenancy. In Spring Boot 1, I had a MongoConfig and a MultiTenantMongoFactory files, which achieved this, which now seem to be entirely ignored (even if I comment these out, the same error occurs). In the previous version of Spring Boot, the project worked fine and the database functioned as desired.
2. The error is encapsulated:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
15:39:16.726 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoAuditingHandler': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#4cacccbf' of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.MongoAuditingRegistrar$MongoMappingContextLookup] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#4cacccbf': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingMongoConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mappingMongoConverter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoMappingContext' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:389)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:691)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1206)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
        at com.foo.bar.Application.main(Application.java:50)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#4cacccbf': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingMongoConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mappingMongoConverter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoMappingContext' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1206)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374)
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingMongoConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mappingMongoConverter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoMappingContext' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1367)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
        ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoMappingContext' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1367)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
        ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.declaredAnnotations(Field.java:1153)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.declaredAnnotations(Field.java:1151)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.getDeclaredAnnotations(Field.java:1139)
        at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.getAnnotations(AccessibleObject.java:207)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.AnnotationBasedPersistentProperty.lambda$populateAnnotationCache$7(AnnotationBasedPersistentProperty.java:122)
        at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.AnnotationBasedPersistentProperty.populateAnnotationCache(AnnotationBasedPersistentProperty.java:120)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.AnnotationBasedPersistentProperty.<init>(AnnotationBasedPersistentProperty.java:88)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentProperty.<init>(BasicMongoPersistentProperty.java:78)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.CachingMongoPersistentProperty.<init>(CachingMongoPersistentProperty.java:50)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext.createPersistentProperty(MongoMappingContext.java:81)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext.createPersistentProperty(MongoMappingContext.java:39)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:542)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:520)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:710)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:389)
        at java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4769)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:562)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:520)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:710)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:389)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:338)
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.initialize(AbstractMappingContext.java:467)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractMappingContext.java:459)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784)
        ... 53 common frames omitted
```

My Application:

```
package com.foo.bar;

//imports

@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@EnableRetry
@ServletComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoAuditing
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableFeignClients(clients = {Client1.class,Client2.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan("com.foo.bar.domain.repository")
public class Application implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Pleaes add the full stacktrace to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the annotation `@EnableMongoRepositories({"path.to.repos"})` above my main class as well as the following pom dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency
```

made the application work eventually. I'm unaware of the reason why, though. My investigation begun by the addition of the annotation, which I saw someone use in a different thread, and afterwards some errors occurred that the dependencies battled.